# JavaScript semi colon issue

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript code

```
var foo = function () {
   var func = function () {
        var one = 0;
        if (one === 0) {
            alert('func');
        }

    }

    return {
        func: func
    };
}

foo = new foo();
foo.func();
```

My above code alerts `func` which is fine. Now When I change the object literal i.e. `return {}` to following

```
return
{
    func: func
}
```

Then it does not return anything. I know why because JavaScript adds semi colon `;` at the end of return. So leave this part for a while, lets take a look back to my original code. When I change the `if` statement to following

```
if (one === 0)
{
    alert('func');
}
```

Then it does alert `func`. **WHY?**. Since in this case javascript should add semi colon at the end of `if(one === 0)` too so I think it should return error.

Wait a sec, there is more. Now lets take your attention back to my original code at the top. Now when I change my inner function to following

```
var func = function ()
{
    //code here
}
```

Then again it executes this code fine and alerts `func`. Again **Why?** Same goes with outer function.

Comment: `return` statements are a special case for this automatic semicolon insertion

Comment: "I know why because JavaScript adds semi colon ; at the end of return". No it doesn't. The grammar just accepts an end-of-statement after `return`.

Comment: I was watching Douglas Crockford presentation and in that he mentioned that semi colons are added at the end of the lines so better put it yourself. Thats why I said here.

Answer (score 2):

No, semicolons aren't inserted at each end of line. [The rules are much more complex](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.9.1) :

> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token (called the
>   offending token) is encountered that is not allowed by any production
>   of the grammar, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the
>   offending token if one or more of the following conditions is true:
>
> 1. The offending token is separated from the previous token by at least one LineTerminator.
> 2. The offending token is }.
>
> When, as the program is parsed from left to right, the end of the
>   input stream of tokens is encountered and the parser is unable to
>   parse the input token stream as a single complete ECMAScript Program,
>   then a semicolon is automatically inserted at the end of the input
>   stream. When, as the program is parsed from left to right, a token is
>   encountered that is allowed by some production of the grammar, but the
>   production is a restricted production and the token would be the first
>   token for a terminal or nonterminal immediately following the
>   annotation "[no LineTerminator here]" within the restricted production
>   (and therefore such a token is called a restricted token), and the
>   restricted token is separated from the previous token by at least one
>   LineTerminator, then a semicolon is automatically inserted before the
>   restricted token. However, there is an additional overriding condition
>   on the preceding rules: a semicolon is never inserted automatically if
>   the semicolon would then be parsed as an empty statement or if that
>   semicolon would become one of the two semicolons in the header of a
>   for statement (section 12.6.3).

The ECMAScript spec gives this recommendation :

> The resulting practical advice to ECMAScript programmers is:
>
> A postfix ++ or -- operator should appear on the same line as its
>   operand.
>
> An Expression in a return or throw statement should start on
>   the same line as the return or throw token.
>
> A label in a break or
>   continue statement should be on the same line as the break or continue
>   token.

But the real practical thing to remember is it's complex, so append the semicolon yourself, don't beg for bugs.